# Importing files from a either src/ or lib/

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, commonjs

I have a package (let's call it `preset`) that imports a component (`component`). Both are maintained by me. For backwards compatibility, `preset` additionally has to import a specific function from `component`, which is only available from a specific file (not the one in the `main` field). To do this, I use the `require('component/lib/file.js')` syntax.

However, `file.js` has side-effects. This is fine normally, but for Webpack builds I also have `lib-mjs` (with ES module syntax for tree shaking). This causes `file.js` to be loaded twice, once indirectly in `lib-mjs` via `component`, and once directly in `lib`.

A few options:

- I could move `file.js` out of `lib`/`lib-mjs` altogether. However, this complicates the build process and messes up the repo structure.
- I could export the specific function anyway. However, since `component` follows the same pattern with a lot of different components, I'd have to change that in a lot of places.
- I could remove the side-effect to some init function. However, this would be a breaking change and involve quite some work.
- I could make sure the side-effect only happens if it hasn't happened already. However, that and the previous change still has the file loaded twice. On top of that, it would require some semi-global state, I don't think I can pull off duck-typing for this one.

Is there some option like `require(require.resolve('component') + '/file.js')` that actually works for both Node and Webpack?